# Ionic v3 use variable in another page

Tags: typescript, variables, ionic-framework

I need to use a variable declared in a function in another page. Let me explain: In home page I take a picture with this:

```
capture(event, fab: FabContainer) {
fab.close();
const cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {

  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  correctOrientation: true


};

this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {

  this.captureDataUrl = ('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
  this.upload();
}, (err) => {

});
```

}

Now I want to send `this.captureDataUrl` to a filter page, make some stuff and send it back to home page updating the existing one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using navCtrl and navParams

Answer (score 0):

You can use events

In your home page would be something like

```
capture(event, fab: FabContainer) {
fab.close();
const cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {

  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  correctOrientation: true


};

this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {

  this.captureDataUrl = ('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
  this.events.publish('pictureEvent',{dataUrl:this.captureDataUrl})
  this.upload();
}, (err) => {

});
}
```

And in your filter page just suscribe to the event and do whatever you need to do

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
...
constructor(private events:Events){
this.events.subscribe('pictureEvent',dataUrl=>console.log(dataUrl))
...
}
```

Comment: Hi it doesn't seems to work. I use this: this.navCtrl.push(FiltriPage); to open the page and this.events.publish('pictureEvent',{dataUrl:this.captureData‌​Url}); to publish the variable. Then in the constructor of filtripage I use this.events.subscribe('pictureEvent',dataUrl=>console.log(da‌​taUrl)); but nothing appear in console. How can I solve?

Comment: I also use public instead of private and add { } after arrow function but nothing